# iOS GoogleMaps SDK - animateToCameraPosition animation finished handler?

Tags: ios, animation, google-maps-mobile, google-maps-sdk-ios

Currently I am using the GoogleMaps SDK for iOS for various operations. 
When calling

```
[self.googleMapsView animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition 
                            cameraWithLatitude:LATITUDE
                                     longitude:LONGITUDE
                                          zoom:ZOOM]];
```

is there a completion handler to determine wether the animation finished or not?

Of course I get with the GMSMapViewDelegate updates about the cameraPosition but how should I check if the animation finished?

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView 
didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position;
```

Comment: On related: didChangeCameraPosition also is called multiple (10+) times on simple swipe or pinch gestures instead of just being called once the map has been changed.

Comment: Im suffering with this because I'm updating a textfield whenever I call this delegate method with the new address retrieved from google maps API, and it's been called so many times that I get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Answer (score 19):

For the reference of future readers of this post, Google Maps SDK for iOS Version 1.4.0 released in July 2013 has added a new delegate method **mapView:idleAtCameraPosition:** which will be fired at the end of any camera movement - be it programatic animation like in this question or user triggered movements.

Answer (score 9):

This might work (I haven't tried it):

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1.0f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
[self.googleMapsView animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition 
                        cameraWithLatitude:LATITUDE
                                 longitude:LONGITUDE
                                      zoom:ZOOM]];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    // ... whatever you want to do when the animation is complete
}];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Basically, this creates an animation transaction that animates your camera movement (change the value for `numberWithFloat:` to change the speed) and you set your own completion block stating what you want to do when the animation is over.  `[CATransaction commit]` is what fires the animation off.

Note: this answer partially based off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15663039/129475).

Comment: sorry but how we can use this code?I don't understand where I need to put it!

Comment: This did not work for me. The completion block is called before the animation ends

Comment: For this to work, the completion block needs to be defined before the animation code.

Answer (score 3):

I came across the issue of google's animation methods lacking completion handlers recently.
The best solution I've found so far is to attach my own completion handler via CATransation API.

```
private func attachCompletionHandlerToGoogleAnimations(@noescape animations: () -> Void, #completion: (() -> Void)!) {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion)
    animations()
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Example usage:

```
attachCompletionHandlerToGoogleAnimations({
    googleMapView.animateToLocation(coordinate)
}) {
    println("camera moved to location \(coordinate)")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is, however...

A method that has worked well for me so far is to set a timer to fire (very) shortly after the location stops updating:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView*)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition*)position {
  // _panTimer is an instance variable of the delegate.
  [_panTimer invalidate];
  _panTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.2
                                      target:self
                                    selector:@selector(_mapHasStoppedMoving)
                                    userInfo:nil
                                     repeats:NO];
  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:_panTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

Comment: but if the user is just making a small change? the timer wouldn't be invalidated and the mapHasStoppedMoving wouldn't be called

Comment: Any change would cause the method to eventually be fired. The _panTimer is an ivar of the class that manages the GMSMapView, otherwise known as the mapView's delegate.

Comment: that's how I do it in 1.1.2. there is an enhancement request on the GMS issue tracker for a delegate method AFTER the change

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT version example:

```
let vancouver = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 49.26, longitude: -123.11)
let calgary = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.05,longitude: -114.05)
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: vancouver, coordinate: calgary)
let cameraPosition = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds)

CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setValue(1.0/*duration in seconds*/, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
    print("animation complete, do whatever you want here")
})
mMapView.animate(with: cameraPosition)
CATransaction.commit()
```