# Controlling Animation Duration in Google Maps for iOS

Tags: ios, animation, google-maps-sdk-ios

The documentation for Google Maps for iOS states that:

> Call one of several methods that allow you to animate the camera moving to a new location. You can control the duration of the animation with CoreAnimation.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to control the animation duration.  I have tried using UIView animations, like:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 5 animations:^{
         GMSCameraPosition *camera = [self newCamera];
        self.mapView.camera = camera;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
```

And I have looked at CALayer animations in CoreAnimation.  However, I don't know how you would apply a layer animation to the map view.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I found the answer ... you can control the animation duration by wrapping one of the animate* methods in a CATransaction, like this:

```
   [CATransaction begin];
   [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1.0f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
   // change the camera, set the zoom, whatever.  Just make sure to call the animate* method.
   [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition: [self newCamera]];
   [CATransaction commit];
```

Answer (score 14):

for Swift 3.0:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setValue(1.5, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
// your camera code goes here, example:
// mapView.animate(with: update)
CATransaction.commit()
```

The bigger the value (1.5 in this case), the slower the animation.

Answer (score 6):

Swift 2.0

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setValue(NSNumber(float: 1.0), forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
// change the camera, set the zoom, whatever.  Just make sure to call the animate* method.
CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

what a pitty that using the same methods you provided there is no way to know if the animation has ended.

Yes I know, there is a **CATransaction completion block** using this method but it does simply not work! :(

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1.0f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
// ... whatever you want to do when the animation is complete
}];

[self.googleMapsView animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition 
                    cameraWithLatitude:LATITUDE
                             longitude:LONGITUDE
                                  zoom:ZOOM]];

[CATransaction commit];
```

And I can't use **MapView:didIdle** hack to know that the animation has ended *because* it will not be called if there is no camera position change.

Anyone knows how to detect animateon has ended event?

FOUND A THREAD ABOUT THIS (solved):
[CATransaction completion being called immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975938/catransaction-completion-being-called-immediately)