# CATransaction completion being called immediately

Tags: ios, caanimation

I'm trying to execute a completion-block after my CAAnimation has finished. However, it seems that animation block is called before my animation completes. The animation still happens correctly though.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:self.dropAndBounceAnimation forKey:@"appearance"];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:completionBlock];
[CATransaction commit];
```

The dropAndBounceAnimation is a CAKeyFrameAnimation on position.y, with a fixed duration.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I'm not sure if this really is the correct fix, but by setting the completion-block **before**  adding the animation for the layer, the completion-block is consistently called at the correct time.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:completionBlock];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:self.dropAndBounceAnimation forKey:@"appearance"];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Yes it is, as per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransaction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CATransaction/setCompletionBlock:): "The completion block object that is guaranteed to be called (on the main thread) as soon as all animations *subsequently added* by this transaction group have completed (or have been removed.)". The key part is "subsequently added".

Comment: @albertamg However, it also states `If no animations are added before the current transaction group is committed (or the completion block is set to a different value,) the block will be invoked immediately.`

Comment: @iWasRobbed yes, and that explains why the block is called before the animation completes if it is set after adding the animation to the transaction group.

Comment: also called immediately if you forgot to set `view.wantsLayer = YES;`

Answer (score 16):

You need to set the completion block before adding the animation.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1.0f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
// ... whatever you want to do when the animation is complete
}];

[self.googleMapsView animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition 
                    cameraWithLatitude:LATITUDE
                             longitude:LONGITUDE
                                  zoom:ZOOM]];

[CATransaction commit];
```

This must trigger the completion block after the completion of that animation on the view.

Answer (score 7):

Here is **Swift 3.0.1, Xcode 8** version:

```
CATransaction.begin()

CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
  print("Transaction completed")
})

print("Transaction started")
view.layer.add(dropAndBounceAnimation, forKey: "appearance")

CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the animation asynchronously:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.startAnimation()
}
```

because it can interfere with view drawing if you make some view setup before calling the animation.