# Error after submitting app to store -[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7.1, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am developing an iOS 7 app that integrates the Google Maps SDK for iOS.

When testing the app on both iOS devices and emulator it works well.

After submitting the app to the store, when I try to access the part that contains the map it crashes. The phone log shows me this error

```
-[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance  0x17da2490 <Error>: 

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 

-[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17da2490'"
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: this may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203991/ios-googlemaps-sdk-animatetocameraposition-animation-finished-handler

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019776/googlemaps-basic-ios-demo-app-crash-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance

Comment: i saw those posts, but my app crashes only after its published to the app store. From xcode it works on both device and emulator

Comment: Can you post the code that crashes, and a call stack for the crash?

Comment: Always build and test your app with the release build settings before submitting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Google maps SDK, 'unrecognized selector' often occurs if you haven't included the `-ObjC` linker flag.

Could it be that you've included `-ObjC` in the debug build settings (which you might be using when running it from XCode), but it's missing in the release build settings (which it would use when you build to submit to the App Store)?

Comment: thank you, i did't included the -ObjC to the release build settings, only to the debug build settings.